# Why function set_widget_size of library "gridster.js" is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridster

I am trying to play around with grister.js library but I am running into some problems.

I have this html file:

```
<div class="gridster">
      <ul>
        <li class="white" data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
                <header>
                <div class="deleteWidgetDiv">X</div>
                <div class="updateWidgetDiv">*</div>

               </header>

        </li>
        <li class="white" data-row="1" data-col="2" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
             <header>
                <div class="deleteWidgetDiv">X</div>
                <div class="updateWidgetDiv">*</div>

               </header>
        </li>
```

In javascript folder I have this file to create the gridster object:

```
$(function(){ 

  $(".gridster ul").gridster({
    widget_margins: [10, 5],
    widget_base_dimensions: [180, 180],
    autogenerate_stylesheet: true,
   resize: {
       enabled:true
     }
  });

});
```

To get hold the API of this object I have create the file below:

```
 $(function(){ 

    var gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster().data('gridster');


    gridster.resize_widget( $('.gridster li').first());


   $(document).on( "click", "#addWidgetButton", function(e) {

   e.preventDefault(); 

gridster.add_widget.apply(gridster, ["<li class='white'><header><div class='deleteWidgetDiv'>X</div></header> </li>"])


 });

    $(document).on( "click", ".deleteWidgetDiv", function() {
  // debugger;

      var y=  $(this).closest( "li" );

     gridster.remove_widget(y);

       });


       $(document).on( "click", ".updateWidgetDiv", function() {


        var x=  $(this).closest( "li" );

       gridster.set_widget_max_size(x,[1,2]);

    });

});
```

http://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/docs/classes/Gridster.html  this is the URL where the API definition for this library is.

Now when I click "x" the function **remove_widget** works fine, but when I click "*" the function **set_widget_max_size** is not working so nothing happens. According to the API definition of this method this should work but something apparently is going wrong and I am not able to figure it out what is going wrong.